# Matlab: how to display the "real" values of an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, format

I have a vector that is caluculated in a script.

After calculation, I display the values to the command window.  It is displayed as follows:

```
finalResults =
1.0e+05 *
0.0001
     0
0.0005
0.0002
0.0001
0.0027
0.0033
0.0001
-0.0000
-0.0000
1.3750
0.0066
```

How do I make it display with the *real* values (i.e. with the `1.0e+05` multiplied in)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format longG` should do the trick. This uses either `long` or `longE`, whichever is shorter *for each element*. Same can be done with `format shortG` if you want shorter sequences.

The reason MATLAB displays numbers like in your question, is because this is the `format short` way of doing things. Look at [`format`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) in the documentation to see all the options.

Example:

```
format shortG
A = [1;1e10;-1];
A =

            1
        1e+10
           -1
format longG
A =

                         1
               10000000000
                        -1
```

Comment: I almost got excited! Hahah. But it seems that didn't do the trick; it now displays as follows (with just more digits):
finalResults =
   1.0e+05 *
   0.000126842700000
...

Comment: It works now. Should've used `longG`, see the answer