# How do I use the Arrhenis Equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to use the equation `k=k0*e^(-Q/RT)` where `T` is 10 variables between 90 and 500, to generate the 10 variables I used `T = linspace(90,500,10)`, but when I try to generate the equation it wont let me, `k0=1200`,`Q=8000`,`R=2` so when I type in `k=k0*exp(-Q./(R.*T)` the numbers are kind of funky with some `0.0000`, am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: Could you paste the concrete code that is giving you issues? Reading pseudocode makes it very unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab: how to display the "real" values of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524059/matlab-how-to-display-the-real-values-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
T = linspace(90,500,10);
k0=1200;
Q=8000;
R=2;
k=k0*exp(-Q./(R.*T));
format longG
k =

  Columns 1 through 3

      5.98693127135402e-17      1.83626027549851e-10      3.07185900119097e-07

  Columns 4 through 6

      2.60112352637493e-05      0.000498552970093129       0.00409767412987074

  Columns 7 through 9

        0.0198590098887835         0.067709291730596         0.180526236997812

  Column 10

         0.402555153483014

results = [T';k'];
```

Nothing wrong there, just the format that went wrong I reckon. For formatting options, see either the documentation on [`format`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524059/matlab-how-to-display-the-real-values-of-an-array/32524236#32524236) question.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, how would I put the k value with its corresponding T value in a table to show the results?

Comment: Please post **everything** you want with this code *directly* into your question and don't ask 'little' things after the correct answer to the initial question has been provided. Besides, this is ridiculously basic.